# ArgumentError in StaticPages#home

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I noob in Rails. I use rails 4.2.4. I have a problem with my contact form. I have an error: `First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty` on the 3 line of this code (contact_form.html.erb):

```
<div class="all-banners-width">
    <figure class="green-background">
        <%= form_for @contact_form do |f| %>
            <p>
                <%= f.label :name %><br>
                <%= f.text_field :name %>
            </p>

            <p>
                <%= f.label :phone %><br>
                <%= f.text_field :phone %>
            </p>

            <p>
                <%= f.label :email %><br>
                <%= f.text_field :email %>
            </p>

            <p>
                <%= f.label :text %><br>
                <%= f.text_field :text %>
            </p>

            <p>
                <%= f.submit %>
            </p>
        <% end %>
    </figure>
</div>
```

My contact_form_controller.rb is:

```
class ContactFormController < ApplicationController

  def contact_form
    @contact_form = ContactForm.new
  end

 def create
    @contact_form = ContactForm.new(contact_form_params)
    @contact_form.save
    redirect_to root_path, notice: "Saved"
 end

  private
    def contact_form_params
      params.require(:contact_form).permit(:name, :phone, :email, :text)
    end
end
```

My DB migration file is:

```
class CreateContactForms < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :contact_forms do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :phone
      t.string :email
      t.string :text

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

If I change 3rd line from contact_form.html.erb to the next:

```
<%= form_for :contact_form do |f| %>
```

then I have not an error, but anyway contact form does not work and there are not any errors I can see.

Can somebody help me? I have not idea, where is problem.

Comment: Can you paste full error here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss action `new` in controller:

```
def new
  @contact_form = ContactForm.new
end
```

your template is rendered with `@contact_form = nil`.

Comment: @verrom What's the name of the file (with template?)

Comment: contact_form_controller.rb,
_contact_form.html.erb
These files?

Comment: I suppose, contact_form

Comment: do you have it on the web?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90872/discussion-between-dimakura-and-verrom).